# How to add sth to state without duplicates? React JS, useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-effect

I have problem with adding sth to state without multiplying it... Case: I have form where user can add multiple photos. All as a Blob goes to state and with useEffect I'm adding it to firebase storage. Then I need to add every url to the state. Right now I have this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (state.propertyName && imgState.images) {
      imgState.images.map((image, i) => {
        storageRef
          .child(`images/${state.propertyName}/${image.name}`)
          .put(image)
          .then((url) => {
            url.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
              setState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                imgUrlArr: state.imgUrlArr ? [...state.imgUrlArr, url] : [url],
              }));
            });
          });
      });
    }
  }, [imgState.images]);
```

More imgs I add, more duplicates I've got. I know why, this line is wrong

```
imgUrlArr: state.imgUrlArr ? [...state.imgUrlArr, url] : [url]
```

but I don't know how to change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try checking before using setState if this url already exists in the state.imgUrlArr with Array method indexOf?

Comment: if the below answer does not work for you please comment I will update my answer

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini nope, not wotking, but still - thanks

Comment: can you please mention the state and the format of update data which you want

Comment: did you have a list in the imgUrlArr?

Comment: I want urls to be added to state.imgUrlArr (array).

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini don't boder - the problem is with url - they are generetad multiple of times after every re-render. I should have checked it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of duplicates you can use Set object like this: 
const deduplicatedArr = new Set(arr)